# Gravity Forms displaying tables as text in Gmail

Tags: wordpress, forms, smtp, gravity

I have Gravity Forms implemented on a website, but when admin notifications are sent through to email (Gmail hosted) the tables are displaying as code.

This is how it's displaying when sent via email. I'm using Sendgrid as SMTP.

```html
<table width="99%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EAEAEA">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr bgcolor="#EAF2FA">
          <td colspan="2">
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><strong>Name</strong></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;">Sample Name</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#EAF2FA">
          <td colspan="2">
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><strong>Email</strong></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><a href='mailto:enquiry@example.com'>enquiry@example.com</a></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#EAF2FA">
          <td colspan="2">
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><strong>Phone</strong></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;">01XXX XXXXXX</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#EAF2FA">
          <td colspan="2">
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><strong>Company Name</strong></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;">Enquiry Company Name Ltd</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#EAF2FA">
          <td colspan="2">
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><strong>Products Available</strong></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;">Request Title</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#EAF2FA">
          <td colspan="2">
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;"><strong>Your message</strong></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td width="20">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <font style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;">This is an example message.</font>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, it used to send as the table itself perfectly formatted. In the meantime, I've set it up to send as plain text for ease of reading, but the person receiving has specifically requested it's displayed as a table.

Can anyone advise on how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you selected to send as plain text. This way gmail strips all html tags and most probably removes the table too.
Try selecting HTML format on emails.